# C# URL Rewriting

Tags: c#, url-rewriting

I have no knowledge of doing this sort so apologies for my lack of code examples (I've been doing internet searches on the subject and I can't seem to find any examples of what I'm trying to do).

I've got a series of URL's which looks something like these:

```
/content/product-A/
/content/product-B/
```

and I need to write a rule to redirect them to the following:

```
/result/?product=producta
/result/?product=productb
```

From what I've read I should be doing this in a rewrite rule in the web.config but other than that I'm really ignorant as to how this would be achieved (if possible).

**Edit from comment:** The products will be something like *my-widget*, *my-super-widget*, *super-gold-widget* etc

Could a more intelligent soul give me some assistance please?

Thanks,
C

Comment: is it an MVC project ?

Comment: It is an MVC project yes

Answer (score 0):

In your `content` controller you probably have something similar to this:

```
     // eg: /content
    // eg: /content/product-A
    [Route("content/{productName?}")]
    public ActionResult View(string productName)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(productName))
        {
            return View("ViewProduct", GetProduct(productName));
        }
        return View("AllProducts", GetProducts());
    }
```

At this point I think you can redirect to a `result` action

```
            // eg: /content
            // eg: /content/product-A
            [Route("content/{productName?}")]
            public ActionResult View(string productName)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(productName))
                {
              productName = productName.Replace("-","").ToLower();
              return RedirectToAction("result", new { product= productName  );
                }
                return View("AllProducts", GetProducts());
            }
```

And you will need any configuration

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, sorry I probably should have elaborated the names of the products will be something like my-widget, my-super-widget, super-gold-widget etc (I wrote product-a, product-b, to make it easier to read but I now realise that was a mistake).

Comment: and you do need to remove all "-" from products names ?

Comment: I do yes my friend

Comment: I think you can do everything via controllers. I edited my answer